# Determine the points from a set of coordinates that will form a line

Tags: c++, algorithm, linear-algebra, cartesian-coordinates

I want to make a program that generates between 10 - 100 random coordinates on the Cartesian plane and it should find which points will form a line.

It should be a combination of at least four points that can form a line. To do this, I can find the slope between the four selected points to find out if they can form a line.

However, the hard part is how can I make a combination of all the points? I want to use the brute force method which finds all combinations of at least four points and then checks the slope between them to see if they can form a line.

Any advice as to how I can approach this problem e.g find the combinations efficiently will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused...  You say you *want* to use the brute force method of checking all combinations -- so just check each combination.  I.e., for any set of 4 points, pick any 2 of them, calculate the equation of the line that they form, and then test whether the other two points satisfy this equation.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I think OP wants all combinations with **at least** 4 points.

Comment: If you want to actually find 4 co-linear random points I suggest you 1) use integers instead of floating point, and 2) limit the size of the domain (the subset of the Cartesian plane).  Using floating point or using a large integer domain will make it very unlikely that 4 random points will be co-linear.

Comment: @Degustaf: You're right.  I've added an answer with a better suggestion.

Comment: Yea, my question is how can I make sure all the combinations of four points have been tested?

Comment: If you would be working with real numbers, the probability to have 4 (or even 3) random points lying on a line is zero. You will have to think of what you want to consider as "lying on a line". E.g. you could make a regression of each 4tuple of points and set an upper limit on the distance from the regression line.

Answer (score 5):

I see no benefit to trying all sets of 4 points.  Just take each pair of points, calculate the equation y = mx + c of the line that they form, and insert each pair (m, c) into an array.  Then sort this array (it doesn't matter whether m or c is the first sort key).  All point pairs belonging to the same line will then appear as contiguous blocks in the sorted array: if there are n points on the same line, there will be n^2 contiguous elements in the corresponding block, but it's easy to identify just the n distinct points.  Time and space complexity: O(n^2 log n).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all combinations because you have two different fail points in your 4-tuple: at 3 and at 4. Clearly if the first 3 aren't linear, the 4th won't make the entire tuple linear. And furthermore, if A-B-C aren't linear, it doesn't matter what the 4th point is, they will *all* fail.

So with that in mind, I'd make a vector of 4 items and call it my result vector, and an index going from 0 to 4 in your result vector, starting at 0. The vector will hold indices in your array of points, and will be initialized with -1 for N/A (yet).

Then for every cycle of the algorithm:

- You increment the result vector item at the result vector index position.
- If the result vector item isn't unique, increment it again. If you reach the end of your array you ran out of items for this. You decrement the result vector index to backtrack. If you're also at the beginning of your result vector you're done. Don't forget to set the item you drop to -1!
- If the index is 3, you check that the points are linear, if not you do nothing.
- If the index is 4, you check that the points are linear and if so you have a solution! Yay! If not you do nothing.
- If the index isn't 3 or 4, you increment the index to get a new point.

Comment: That sounds good, but my main question is how can I make sure that all the combinations of four points have been tested?

Comment: I think I got your point. So to clarify, you're saying that I store 4 points in a vector and each time check if they are linear. If the first index of the vector reaches end of array, it goes back to 0 and the second index of the vector starts to increment and check for linear points?

Comment: No, if you reach the end you check for a solution, then backtrack like usual (`--index;`). If you reach the *beginning* of the array and try to backtrack you're out of any more combinations and end the algorithm. Also -1 is the invalid value since these things are indices in a larger array of items, and arrays are 0-based in the C world.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to apply [PCA Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) on your point set.

Answer (score 0):

Usually four random points does not form a line due to their randomness. If you want to do something like that you can fine the linear regression of every distinct four points sets, check respective variance and then choose sets where variance is under a threshold that you must determined in order to see when points are "aligned on a line".

Answer (score 0):

You only have to consider all combinations of pairs of points. These defines all the possible lines formed by the points.

You thus consider points (Pi,Pj) where i is in the range 1 to n, and j is in the range i+1 to n.

We use the line equation of the form `ax+by+c=0` because it is trivial to determine and has no degenerated case (where its slope is infinite).

With two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), that equation is `(y2-y1)x+(x2-x1)y+(x1y2-x2y1) = 0`.

To test if a point (x3,y3) is on this line, simply replace x with x3 and y with y3 in the equation. If the result is 0, the point is on the line. Since we use floating points with limited precision we test `abs((y2-y1)*x3+(x2-x1)*y3+(x1y2-x2y1)) < epsilon` where `epsilon` is a very small value.

For each line (pair (Pi,Pj)), you test all points Pk with k in the range j+1 to n if it belongs to the line. You keep track of all the points you find on the line and print the result if the number is bigger then 2 (total > 4).

You do this for all pairs of points (Pi,Pj).

Do I have to provide the code ?